# LINQ query with group count

Tags: sql, .net, linq

I'm trying to produce a linq sentence but I got stuck.
The SQL I want to mimic is:

```
select count(table1.id) as rCount1, count(table2.id) as rCount2, table.name 
from name 
inner join table1 on table1.table_id = table.id 
inner join table2 on table2.table_id = table.id 
group by table.id
```

I can't realy figure it out...

Comment: So *show* your efforts! And remember that most of the time it's important to know what kind of LINQ it's about *and* that nearly always navigation properties work better than LINQ joins.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
from t in table
join t1 in table1
    on t1.id equals t.id
join t2 in table2
on t2.id equals t.id
group t by t.id into g
select new
{
    rCount1 = g.Count(k => k.t1.id),
    rCount2 = g.Count(k => k.t2.id),
    name = g.key.name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
from a in contex.name
from b in contex.table1.where(x=>x.id==a.id)
from c in contex.table2.where(x=>x.id==a.id)
group a by a.Id into g
select new{rCount1 = g.Count(x => x.t1.id), rCount2 = g.Count(x => x.t2.id),
name = g.key.name }
```